# PHP with MS SQL Server not working

Tags: php, sql-server

This my first time to create php form. I want to submit the form data to ms sql server database in my web server. I am using IIS ver 7.5.7600.16385 and ms sql server 2014 express edition and ms sql server management studio 2017.
I m not able to connect to my sql server using the simple below file:

I checked all the configuration required in terms of dll in EXT folder , but not working.the follwoing are dll files :

```
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
- my php vesrion is 5.6.31
```

This is my file php code:

```
<?php 
 $mssqldriver = '{SQL Server}'; 
 $mssqldriver = '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}'; 
 $mssqldriver = '{ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}'; 
 $hostname='127.0.0.1'; $dbname='BGEnqiry'; $username='sa'; 
 $password='123321'; 
 $conn=newPDO("odbc:Driver=$mssqldriver;Server=$hostname;Database=$dbname", $username, $password); 

if( $conn ) { 
 echo "Connection established.<br />"; 
}
else{ 
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />"; 
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); } ?>
```

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting you code in a comment

Comment: when I run the file in the browser it showing the following;-  "; }else{ echo "Connection could not be established.<br />"; die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); }

Comment: @AbuNuraan Again, please trye to use the **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49522366/edit)** link instead of posting multiple comments.

Comment: `die()` will receive a string for a message. move the `print_r` so it is right above it